# How to verify installed os type as minimal virtual machine

Tags: 10.04, virtualization

Trying to install Ubuntu 10.04 as guest.

> Press F4 and choose Minimal Virtual Machine and then > selected Install Ubuntu Server

Now is there a way to confirm that installed Machine is Minimal VM rather than other Normal/Minimal

after installing it is still showing kernel type as

```
 2.6.32-38-generic-pae
```

Comment: Please add some detail: What do you mean by "trying to install as a guest" ? You mean as opposed to your host? What host are you running? What VM system are you using? Which screen says "press f4 etc..". WHat is showing that kernel type (how do you get it), what are you expecting (a different kernel for a server install? why?) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 cat /proc/modules |wc -l
```

and compare modules, minimal vm have less modules than normal installation.